# Maintain selected rows on ajaxRequestFunc (or setData)

Tags: tabulator

the documentation of persistent selection states: *By default Tabulator will maintain selected rows when the table is filtered, sorted or paginated (but NOT when the setData function is used)...*

In my application I'm using `ajaxRequestFunc` and it doesn't persists the selection after page change in a multi page, server side paginated table. Is there a way to persist them?